# Finding admob owners email id

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play, admob

Is there anyway I can find my admob owner account email by the AdMob App id?

for example my app id is following and I need to locate the original email id that is being used for this AdMob

`ca-app-pub-234124123412354/3412341234`

I used two different email ids for Developer Account and AdMob Account. Due to the app failure in making revenue I didn't focus on the AdMob for long period and now I can't even recall the email id.

Comment: How do I login to email using this Id, can you elaborate?

Comment: misunderstood your question. have you tried troubleshooter provided on this link? https://support.google.com/admob/faq/3364907?hl=en#3178280 , there is no way to link your publisher id to email address